# I got an error when I try to retrieve data from the database via json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am working with Yii 1 and I have a issues when I try to retrieve the province's cities via json_encode from the server.

The error happens when I retrieve more than 30k records.

```
Unknown error 200 . textStatus: parsererror. errorThrown SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"
```

Another use case cities' province works fine.

Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?

```
//PHP Code
public function actionGetDinamicCities() {
    $code = $_POST['code_province'];
    // Busqueda de Registros dependiendo el codigo de Ciudad recibido.
    $cities = City::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'city_name', 
                                                   'condition'=>'state_code=:code_province', 
                                                   'params'=>array(':code_province'=>$code)
                                            ));
    // Creacion de un arreglo clave=>valor para un modelo dado
    $citiesList = generateList($cities, 'id', 'city_name');     
    echo json_encode($citiesList);
}

//JQuery Code
$('#Address_id_province').change(function() {
    var data = { "code_province" : $(this).val() };
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'GetDinamicCities',
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {              
            var options = '<option value>Select a City</option>';
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            getError(jqXHR.status, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });     

function getError(status, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    switch (status) {
        case 404:
            console.log('status: File not found. textStatus: ' + textStatus + '. errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        case 500:
            console.log('Status: Server Error. textStatus: ' + textStatus + '. errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        case 0:
            console.log('status: Request aborted. textStatus: ' + textStatus + '. errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        default:
            console.log('Unknown error ' + status+ ' . textStatus: ' + textStatus + '. errorThrown ' + errorThrown);
    }
}
```

UPDATE

This is the code that I use to get the city' provinces. I separated the keys and values because Chrome and IE sorts it by key and I want it by value.

```
    $code = $_POST['code_country'];

    $states = States::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'state_name', 
                                               'condition'=>'country_code=:code', 
                                               'params'=>array(':code'=>$code)
                                        ));

    $statesList = generateList($states, 'state_code', 'state_name');

    $statesListSorted = array();        
    $statesListSorted['k'] = array_keys($statesList);  
    $statesListSorted['v'] = array_values($statesList);         
    $json = json_encode($statesListSorted); 

    echo $json;
```

The javascript that handled the answer from the server is similar to the cities.

Comment: Look at the data that is coming back, there is probably an error message embedded in it instead of your JSON data, or does your data contain `<`s? JSON doesn't have a limit except for server memory

Comment: Yes, please read the update. It works fine to this code. But I dont know why it give that error. The only different is the amount of records

Comment: You did not address my comment, I'm saying you could be running into memory problems, look at your network tab and look at the data that is coming back, it may contain an error message

Comment: You are right. I got this error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in C:\wamp\bin\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php on line 1911". Is there a way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running out of memory. Two suggestions:

- *Recommeded*: Search/page the data instead. 30K records is a lot to try to display, users don't usually want to see that many records at once
- *Discouraged*: Change your memory settings See http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/14/increase-php-memory-limit/ This may or may not be allowed if you're in a hosted environment

  - php.ini:  `memory_limit = 32M`
  - programatically: `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I will do your recommend and try the other way that you give me